How do I plot GAM model with log transformed response
I created a GAM model using mgcv. My response variable is log transformed. I would like to plot this model using gratia. However, I want to make sure the y-axis is exponentiated after I plot it using the draw function in gratia. Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance!
Below is a snipet of my code.
gam.mod1 <- gam(log(sum7) ~ tap_type.fac + aq_race___1.factor + cityfac +
                  aq_race___2.factor + aq_race___3.factor + aq_race___4.factor
                + aq_race___5.factor + aq_race___99.factor + s(aq_age),family= gaussian, 
                data=d2.male)
draw(gam.mod1, residuals=TRUE)

Forgot to mention that my response variable is continuous and I log-transformed it to improve diagnostics.

Unfortunately I have never used gratia, but the itsadug package allows for plotting GAM models and you can specify the argument transform = exp in order to do what you are talking about

This won't work with the residuals = TRUE element (though in this case you can add the actual response data, not partial residuals), but, you can use smooth_estimates() and it's draw() method:

m <- gam.mod1 # to save typing (am doing this on a tablet)

m |>
  smooth_estimates() |>
  add_confint() |>
  draw(fun = exp, constant = model_constant(m)) &
  # add raw data on
  geom_point(data = d2.male, aes(x = aq_age, y = sum7))

As you model has a load of factors, however, the model constant term (the intercept) refers to the combination of reference levels of the factors. As a result it is not representative of the data on average but for this specific set of observations whose covariates take the reference level of the respective factors. To address this, you could change the contrasts on those factors to sum contrasts. But easier would be to just supply the mean of the response on the log scale as the constant:
log_mean_sum7 <- with(d2.male, mean(log(sum7), na.rm = TRUE))

m |>
  smooth_estimates() |>
  add_confint() |>
  draw(fun = exp, constant = log_mean_sum7) &
  # add raw data on
  geom_point(data = d2.male, aes(x = aq_age, y = sum7))

Now we are adding the grand mean of the response on the log scale (it has to be on the log scale as that is how the model is fitted) as the constant. Previously, we'd be adding the model intercept term, which in the presence of factors with R's default contrast coding will refer to the combination of reference levels of all your factors.
Note that with both the above code examples, we are not using anything about the other covariates (except for the constant being for the reference level combinations in the first example); as such this is a partial effect; it shows the effect of the smooth on the response, on a suitable scale, given the estimates of the other terms in the model.
What you appear (from the comment you just left) to want to do is actually generate predictions from the model for certain combinations of your covariates. If so, you will need to decide which combinations of factor levels you predict at. If you just want to predict at the modal level for each factor, then all you would need for this is:
ds <- data_slice(m, aq_age = evenly(aq_age))

fv <- fitted_values(m, data = ds) |>
  mutate(
    across(
      any_of(
        c(".fitted", ".lower_ci", ".upper_ci")
      ),
      .fns = \(x) exp(x)
    )
  )

You can be more specific about which levels of the factor you predict at by specifying those levels in the data_slice() call:
ds <- data_slice(
  m,
  aq_age = evenly(aq_age),
  cityfac = level(cityfac, "Boston") # give a city name in your data
)

for example, and you can also tell mgcv to exclude certain terms from the model using the exclude argument to predict(), which is also an argument you can pass to fitted-values(), e.g. (pseudo code)
fv <- fitted_values(m, data = ds, exclude = "tap_type.fac<level>") |>
  mutate(
    across(
      any_of(
        c(".fitted", ".lower_ci", ".upper_ci")
      ),
      .fns = \(x) exp(x)
    )
  )

where tap_type.fac<level> would be the name of a term shown in summary(m) for the level of the factor tap_type.fac you want to exclude. As you can tell, you will need to exclude many model terms this way to remove all effects of a factor except the reference level info.
That's where terms comes in; with it you can select only those terms you want in the model predictions
trms <- c("(Intercept)", "s(aq_age)", "cityfacr<level2>", "cityfac<level3>",
  ....)
# etc, replacing `<levelX>` with the levels as per the names of terms
# in the output from `summary(m) that you want to include
fv <- fitted_values(m, data = ds, terms = trms) |>
  mutate(
    across(
      any_of(
        c(".fitted", ".lower_ci", ".upper_ci")
      ),
      .fns = \(x) exp(x)
    )
  )


Thank you! When I run this code, the curve isn't centered around the data. Why is that? Also, does the draw function in gratia use mean or median values for the other covariates in my model? and what is used as for the model_constant(m)? I'm assuming that's the intercept. Sorry for all the questions. TIA

You'll need to show how far off from the data it is, but you shouldn't expect it to be right through the middle because that's not the model you fitted and the log / exp are non-linear transformations. Also, because you have factors in the model, technically what I showed is only for the reference level (combination of levels) for the factors. You would need to provide some other constant to shift the data around for the other levels. If you read ?model_constant you will be enlightened (but yes, it is the model intercept). The draw() method here knows nothing about your other covariates

Thank you so much! This clears things up a lot and helped me understand. and you are correct, I am looking to generate predictions so your code is extremely helpful. I have 2 additional questions. How would I then plot the fitted values (fv in your code)? Additionally, is it possible to have separate curves for different values of a categorical variable (such as the city factor variable)? Sorry to inundate you with so many questions

When you create ds with data_slice(), use evenly(cityfac) instead of level() and you'll get fitted values over range of aq_age for each level of the cityfac factor. How you plot this is up to you. I use ggplot, so I'll add a quick example with more pseudocode shortly, but if you just try it an look at the output fv it should be obvious how to plot it using base R or ggplot, depending on what you already know about plotting in R.

Thanks! Yeah I think I was initially confused with how you plotted the first pseudocode you left but I ended up using ggplot to graph it and looks great! Thank you!
